# How can I see the formulas of an excel spreadsheet in pandas / python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlsx

I would like to read in an excel spreadsheet to python / pandas, but have the formulae instead of the cell results.

For example, if cell A1 is 25, and cell B1 is =A1, I would like my dataframe to show:

```
25    =A1
```

Right now it shows:

```
25    25
```

How can I do so?

Comment: I'm fairly certain there is no built-in way to do this in `pandas`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga agreed, though it's always nice to receive confirmation. Hopefully there's a package or something that can allow for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`OpenPyXL`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html) provides this capacity out-of-the-box. See [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) and [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/pandas.html#converting-a-worksheet-to-a-dataframe). An example:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'empty_book.xlsx')
sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
name = sheet_names[0]
sheet_ranges = wb[name]
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet_ranges.values)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397769/openpyxl-worksheet-object-has-no-attribute-values

Comment: Looks like someone else got to it before I did. Also ,you should accept this post as an answer.

Comment: Was just waiting to validate. Now I have. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AlekseyBilogur any idea how we can do in CSV?

Comment: Hi @AlekseyBilogur I did give this a try, while this method reads the formula, but it seems to be removing the value itself? I read and just wrote the excel into new file, it maintained the formula, formatting and everything but truncated all values in it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. I recently found a package that solves this issue in a quite sophisticated way. It is called portable-spreadsheet (available via `pip install portable-spreadsheet`). It basically encapsulates `xlsxwriter`. Here is a simple example:

```
import portable_spreadsheet as ps
sheet = ps.Spreadsheet.create_new_sheet(5, 5)
# Set values
sheet.iloc[0, 0] = 25  # Set A1
sheet.iloc[1, 0] = sheet.iloc[0, 0]  # reference to A1
# Export to Excel
sheet.to_excel('output/sample.xlsx')
```

It works in a similar way as Pandas Dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

There is one option to do this using [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) and pandas modules.
[xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) provides a way to automate the excel via python scripts.

Create one "sample.xlsx" file and add random formula in range("A1").

Below is the sample code which will read the value as well as the formula from the given file:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

wbk = xw.Book('sample.xlsx')
ws = wbk.sheets[0]
print(ws.cells(1,1).value)
print(ws.cells(1,1).formula)
```

Same thing applies on range as well. You can assign the `range.value` into dataframe and vice versa.
In case you want to get formulas from big range, you can get that too, but it will return tuple.

Hope this is helpful at some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Use [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/). This is a very useful tool in Python, it has detailed documentation and videos. Good luck!