# Openpyxl: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

My goal is to read in an excel file and view the codes in a pandas dataframe (i.e. '= A3') rather than the resulting values from excel executing the codes, which is the pandas default if read in using pandas.

My goal was described here: [How can I see the formulas of an excel spreadsheet in pandas / python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102674/how-can-i-see-the-formulas-of-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-pandas-python/)

Openpyxl is supposed to support this, but I can't get the import to function correctly. Anyone spot the error?

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

df = pd.DataFrame()
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'name.xlsx')
sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
name = sheet_names[0]
sheet_ranges = wb[name]
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet_ranges.values)

> AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'values'
```

(Note: the exact implementation of the answer at the linked question yields `KeyError: 'Worksheet range names does not exist.'` My code above resolved this, but then gets stuck as described.)

Comment: The linked answer uses `.value` not `.values`

Comment: `.value` yields the same error.

Comment: You're calling `.value` on a worksheet, not a cell. Try using `iter_rows()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your version of openpyxl, It seems you have an older version.

[openpyxl 2.4.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl)

```
import openpyxl
print(openpyxl.__version__)
```

Values property for worksheets were added only from [2.4.0-a1 (2016-04-11)](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/changes.html)