# Does pandas read in excel formulae?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel spreadsheet which has some formulae with random number generators. This is so every time I reopen the spreadsheet, the numbers are slightly different.

I noticed that if I opened the spreadsheet, didn't touch the numbers, then read the spreadsheet into a pandas dataframe, the data in pandas is different to the excel I have open.

Does reading in the spreadsheet into pandas have the same effect as reopening the spreadsheet, and therefore randomizes the numbers each time?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102674/how-can-i-see-the-formulas-of-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-pandas-python

Comment: Did you save the spreadsheet after opening it in Excel, but before reading it in pandas?

Comment: @IanS Thanks, yes that seems to be the issue - I hadn't saved the spreadsheet in between opening it and importing it to pandas. Feel free to post an answer below and I'll upvote + mark as correct