# Find and replace file name in Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

based on [Find and Replace text in xlsx file with python openpyxl in whichever cell it appear in within sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841732/find-and-replace-text-in-xlsx-file-with-python-openpyxl-in-whichever-cell-it-app) I tried to do the following:

The file "example.xlsx" contains cells where I want to replace "'path[file.xlsx]tab1'!A5" by "'path[file.xlsm]tab1'!A5". I tried:

```
#! python3
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("example.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

i = 0
for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
    s = str(ws.cell(r,c).value)
    if s != None and "xlsx" in s: 
        ws.cell(r,c).value = s.replace("xlsx","xlsm") 

        print("row {} col {} : {}".format(r,c,s))
        i += 1

wb.save('targetfile.xlsx')
print("{} cells updated".format(i))
```

But it did not replace anything. What shall I do?

Comment: Side note: after ``s = str( ... )`` ``s`` will be a string, so ``s != None`` will always be ``True``, so you might as well remove this check.

Comment: `for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):` is looping through every cell in the sheet - you may be able to define a more efficient loop than this

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows and it only works to overwrite the originally opened workbook when i specify a file path on the save, so simply modifying penultimate line to this works if you want to overwrite the opened file

```
wb.save(".\\example.xlsx")
```

I can save a new file (as you are doing, opening `example.xlsx` and saving `targetfile.xlsx`) without specifying a path but for some reason to overwrite an existing file you need to have a path

Comment: I changed the code to: "#! python3

import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("example.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

i = 0
for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        s = str(ws.cell(r,c).value)
        if s != None and "xlsx" in s:
            s=s.replace("xlsx","xlsm") 
            ws.cell(r,c).value = s
            print("row {} col {} : {}".format(r,c,s))
            i += 1

wb.save(".\\example.xlsx")
print("{} cells updated".format(i))" which gives: "0 cells updated."

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
#! python3
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("example.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

i = 0
for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        s = str(ws.cell(r,c).value)
        if s != None and "xlsx" in s:
        s=s.replace("xlsx","xlsm") 
        ws.cell(r,c).value = s
        print("row {} col {} : {}".format(r,c,s))
        i += 1

wb.save('targetfile.xlsx')
print("{} cells updated".format(i))
```

But it did not replace anything.

Comment: its something to do with file permissions on save, if you save to a different file name it works

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're looking in the correct file? You have two files example.xlsx and targetfile.xlsx. The changes will be seen in targetfile.xlsx not in example.xlsx.

[Working Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcQeS.png)

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("mydoc.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
i = 0
for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        s = str(ws.cell(r,c).value)
        if "xlsx" in s: 
            ws.cell(r,c).value = s.replace("xlsx","xlsm") 

            print("row {} col {} : {}".format(r,c,s))
            i += 1

wb.save('mycode.xlsx')
print("{} cells updated".format(i))
```

Comment: Yes, I had a look in targetfile.xlsx and nothing was replaced. Python shell output is: "0 cells updated"