# Applying the Lambda function for Style data in the excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, pandas-styles

I am facing an issue while applying an applymap() with lambda function to replace the existing string from Styler Dataframe. 
E.g. We have to replace Change with 'yellow' color and New with 'green'. I stuck in applying the function to replace value from Styler Dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

out=r'C:\Users\test\changes.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\test\update.xlsx')

def mycolors(val):
    #print(val)
    stra = 'Changed-'
    stri = 'New-'
    color = 'white'
    if stra in str(val):
        color = 'yellow'
    elif stri in str(val):
        color = 'green'
        #print(type(color))
    return 'background-color: %s' % color


df = df.style.applymap(mycolors)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).replace('Changed-',''))

#print(df)
df.to_excel(out, header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: That looks correct to me, what problem are you seeing exactly?

Comment: It is getting an exception while using applymap() for second time with lambda function, to remove 'Changed-' . It is happening only when I am using lambda along with style function to color excel.

Comment: Great, would you mind posting the stacktrace for the exception in the question?

Comment: Im getting this warning, 'CSSWarning: Ill-formatted attribute: expected a colon in 'nan'
  CSSWarning,'. But if I run by keeping single applymap it is working for replace function. But there is no change in output, it just highlights without removing the Changed- tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem got resolved by using openpyxl, by reopening the excel and replacing the content from it.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52277175/12843219)

Answer (score 0):

After the first applymap the dataframe is now a `pandas.styler`. What you want to do is using the format of styler to access the text of cells:[pandas.styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html)
`Styler.format: Formats the text display value of cells.`

```
df = df.style.applymap(mycolors)
df = df.format(lambda x: str(x).replace('Changed-',''))
```

Comment: it is not working, after writing to xlsx it is not replacing the tag 'Changed-' and there is no error in the code.