# Pandas replacing excel formula cell value by 0 when importing

Tags: python, pandas

I try to import a excel file using pandas but as you can see on the screenshot, the value is directly produced by a formula.

[image]

Here's the result after having it importing with pandas:

```py
xlsx = '2019-07-09_normalized--09072019.xlsx' 
df_xlsx = pd.read_excel(xlsx, index_col=0)
```

[image]

Do you think there's a solution by passing a parameter in the read_excel fonction for example, or found a trick by converting the excel in a csv file during import?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see the formulas of an excel spreadsheet in pandas / python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102674/how-can-i-see-the-formulas-of-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-pandas-python)

Comment: Actually it's the same context but different problem: "have the formulae instead of the cell results." In my case I get a null value after import where the cell's value is generated by a formula.

Comment: Maybe you can share your code

Comment: there's no code involved except very basic excel import in pandas: 
xlsx = '2019-07-09_normalized--09072019.xlsx' 
df_xlsx = pd.read_excel(xlsx, index_col=0)
(I edit the question with)

Comment: So, at the end, I'm afraid there's no simple conversion solution, as the data ain't in the cell:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517508/read-excel-cell-value-and-not-the-formula-computing-it-openpyxl
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116162/python-openpyxl-data-only-true-returning-none