# Editing Excel Formulas in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have this excel file

| employee Salary | Month | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 5 | 50000 |
| 20000 | 7 | 14000 |

So now in the sum column, there is a formula `=A2*B2`, for all the rows in the table.

Now, how to read these formulas in python from my excel sheet and make them dynamic so if I want to change the formula to `=A2+B2` for all the rows,in future I can do it easily.

Comment: Related question: [How to save xls as csv so that formulas show as text?](https://superuser.com/questions/466419/how-to-save-xls-x-as-csv-file-so-that-formulas-show-as-text)

Comment: Maybe this can give you a start: [How can I see the formulas of an excel spreadsheet in pandas / python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102674/how-can-i-see-the-formulas-of-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-pandas-python)

Comment: But then how to edit it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple example using openpyxl for multiplication and sum between two numbers in each row.

For the multiplication example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws['A1'] = 10000
ws['A2'] = 20000
ws['B1'] = 5
ws['B2'] = 7

ws['C1'].value = ws['A1'].value * ws['B1'].value
ws['C2'].value = ws['A2'].value * ws['B1'].value
print(ws['C1'].value, ws['C2'].value)
```

For the sum example:

```
ws['C1'].value = ws['A1'].value + ws['B1'].value
ws['C2'].value = ws['A2'].value + ws['B2'].value
print(ws['C1'].value,ws['C2'].value)
```